# How to connect Ubuntu to AirPlay speakers placed in another network?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, bluetooth

I have Ubuntu 21.10 with ip 192.168.0.1 connected to a router having a static ip WAN=192.168.0.2 and Gateway=192.168.0.1; basically my Ubuntu *is* the Gateway. The router's LAN address is 192.168.1.1. In LAN I have some KEF SLX WIFI speakers to which I can connect from my iPhone and Windows 10 computer, both in router's LAN.

I also want to connect to the speakers from my Ubuntu (192.168.0.1) too; how should I configure the router (or Ubuntu) to have it?

I already enabled *Make discoverable Apple AirTunes sound devices available locally* in `paprefs` (used `sudo ln -sv '/usr/lib/pulse-15.0+dfsg1' /usr/lib/pulse-15.0`) but *locally* means 192.168.0.0/24 for Ubuntu.
In the end Ubuntu machine must remain the Gateway for the router.

Comment: The short answer is that you just need a path from one network to the other and the devices on both should be able to reach each other. You don't really have enough info here to give you more direction than that. 

You didn't mention it but I'm guessing that your networks are /24, right? Whats the full topology (setup) of the networks? How is the 192.168.1.0 network connected to the 192.168.1.0 network?

Comment: Thanks, I already mentioned that I use a router to connect LAN to WAN. Anyway, meanwhile I figured it out too that I have to include my Ubuntu in LAN too (besides using it as a gateway too).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to access AirPlay LAN devices by adding Ubuntu server into the LAN with an additional cable. Basically my network now looks this way:

[image: AirPlay available to my Ubuntu based Gateway]